# Perl locale warnings on Debian

Tags: linux, perl, debian

I'm getting this warning:

```
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:  
    LANGUAGE = (unset),  
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"  
are supported and installed on your system.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root.

Comment: Paul's suggestion is likely to be solution. Btw isn't this more a system administration related question than strictly a *programming* question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a locale, easiest may be adding

```
LANG=C
```

or

```
LANG=en_US
```

or whichever setting you like best in the file `/etc/environment`.

This usually only happens in very bare server environments or `chroot`s.

Comment: how can i do that, i'm new in linux

Comment: What you could then do is to a) click on the up-arrow for my answer to give it 'credit' and / or b) accept my answer a solution to your question.  You can do a) for any question where you like answers and b) for you questions you asked.